# ggplot2 uses incorrect x-values for time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting data from 18:00 until 21:00. As you can see in the first screenshot, the data has a large time-gap from 18:13-20:47, but this is not shown in the chart. So the dots are wrongly plotted. During that time, also a gap in the y-values arised. That is actually visible in the chart.

[image]

The second screenshot shows the plot. There's a gap in the y values, but the gap in the x values is missing.

```
usd = dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT timestamp, refPrice FROM `balance` where timestamp>'2017-09-27 18:00:00' AND timestamp < '2017-09-27 21:00:00' ORDER BY `id` DESC")
data = fetch(usd, n=-1)
ggplot(aes(x = timestamp, y = refPrice), data=data) + geom_point()
```

[image]

mysql column:

```
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

It's also a pity that all timestamps are shown on the x-axis, so that they overlap.

Comment: Seems like it imports the timestamps as strings, you need to parse them first with lubridate::ymd or as.Date

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Splendid, thanks :-D. Please make it the answer. hint: `data$timestamp <- ymd_hms(data$timestamp)` tested and works.